# Modifying multiple elements in a list randomly

Tags: python, list, random, pygame, element

I'm trying to change a single element in a list in this case a pygame.rect but I don't get
how I use a functions on the element?

```
leftOrRightOrUpOrDown = random.randint(0,1,2,3)
    if leftOrRightOrUpOrDown == 0:
        rabbit in rabbits[] move(x-1, y)
    elif leftOrRightOrUpOrDown == 1:
        rabbit in rabbits[] move(x+1, y)
    elif leftOrRightOrUpOrDown == 2:
        rabbit in rabbits[] move(x, y-1)
    elif leftOrRightOrUpOrDown == 3:
        rabbit in rabbits[] move(x, y+1)
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
The rest of the game loop:

```
startGame = True
while startGame == True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                moveRight = False
                moveLeft = True
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                moveRight = True
                moveLeft = False
            if event.key == K_UP:
                moveDown = False
                moveUp = True
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                moveDown = True
                moveUp = False
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                moveLeft = False
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                moveRight = False
            if event.key == K_UP:
                moveUp = False
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                moveDown = False

    rabbitCounter += 1
    if rabbitCounter >= NEW_RABBIT:
        rabbitCounter = 0
        rabbits.append(pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOW_WIDTH
    - RABBIT_SIZE), random.randint (0, WINDOW_HEIGHT - RABBIT_SIZE),
    RABBIT_SIZE, RABBIT_SIZE))



    #windowSurface.fill(BLACK)
    windowSurface.blit(background_image,[0,0])


    if moveDown and player.bottom < WINDOW_HEIGHT:
        player.top += MOVE_SPEED
    if moveUp and player.top > 0:
        player.top -= MOVE_SPEED
    if moveLeft and player.left > 0:
        player.left -= MOVE_SPEED
    if moveRight and player.right < WINDOW_WIDTH:
        player.right += MOVE_SPEED

    windowSurface.blit(playerImage, player)
    for rabbit in rabbits:
        windowSurface.blit(rabbitImage, rabbit)

    rabbitMovement = random.choice([(-1,0), (1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1)])
    for rabbit in rabbits:
        rabbit.move(*rabbitMovement)


    for rabbit in rabbits[:]:

        if player.colliderect(rabbit):
            windowSurface.blit(rabbitImageTwo, rabbit)
            windowSurface.blit(playerImageTwo, player)

        def explosion():
            for rabbit in rabbits:
                if player.colliderect(rabbit) and (moveLeft == False and
        moveRight == False and moveUp == False and
        moveDown == False):
                     rabbits.remove(rabbit)

        if player.colliderect(rabbit) and (moveLeft == False and
    moveRight == False and moveUp == False and moveDown == False):
            t = Timer(3, explosion)
            t.start()

    if len(rabbits) == 0:
        rabbitCounter = 0
        windowSurface.blit (text, (210, 104))
        startGame = False


    pygame.display.update()
    mainClock.tick(40)



while startGame == False:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

the stepmovement

```
    stepMovementNegative = random.randrange(0, -6, 2)

    stepMovementPositive = random.randrange(0, 6, 2)

    rabbitMovement = [((stepMovementNegative),0), ((stepMovementPositive), 0)
                      , (0, (stepMovementNegative)), (0, (stepMovementPositive))]
    for rabbit in rabbits:
        rabbit.move_ip(*random.choice(rabbitMovement))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is something like

```
movement = random.choice([(-1, 0), (1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1)]) # choose tuple (x, y)
for rabbit in rabbits: # work through all rabbits
    rabbit.move(*movement) # apply movement tuple to rabbit
```

This avoids the unnecessary `if:` checking and "magic numbers" for movement directions. Note that this gives the same movement to each `rabbit`; to make them all different move the `choice` *inside* the `for` loop:

```
movements = [(-1, 0), (1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1)]
for rabbit in rabbits:
    rabbit.move(*random.choice(movements))
```

Comment: I think your improvement is good but the rabbit in rabbits doesn't seem to move at all. Maybe I have put the code in the wrong place of the code structure?

Comment: @user3232394 try changing `move` to `move_ip`

Comment: Okay the `move` to `move_ip` worked but they seem to move in the same space, any thoughts on how to make the random movement move more?

Comment: Bear in mind that the small random movements you are applying *average to zero*. If you want the rabbits to move more, you could make the step length a random choice too, and consider applying some bias to give them an overall direction of movement.

Comment: I tried it like this in the question up top but get a traceback.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rickard\My Programs\Python\slutarbete\Slutarbete.py", line 162, in <module>
    stepMovementNegative = random.randrange(0, -6, 2)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\random.py", line 205, in randrange
    raise ValueError("empty range for randrange()")
ValueError: empty range for randrange() <-- this traceback

Comment: `random.randrange(0, -6, 2)` makes no sense, you can't get to -6 from 0 by adding 2s - switch to `random.randrange(0, -6, -2)`

Comment: Okay that worked, Is there any way to make them more smooth somehow and to stay within the windowSurface?

Comment: "Smoothness" and random movement probably aren't too compatible! You might need to revise your approach away from completely random. You can certainly check position and keep them in the window (for example, see the [introductory `pygame` example](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/intro/intro.html)) but, again, random movements will sometimes try to move them out of bounds.